# How to store user detail with user session in express js and express-mysql-session?

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am using express js , express-mysql-session and passport js for session management. The problem I am facing is that the express-mysql-sessionstores the session details in the predefined columns.

The session table created by express-mysql-session contains data column which stores the session details as json string.

How can I know the sessions of a particular user? For example Admin wants to terminate session of a particular user.